# using an aggregate function in an update query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to sum the field AmountPaid and update the field SumOfAmountPaid with that value. this is for a school assessment. Ive looked around online for help but all the solutions have gone way over my head because we havent been taught how to use SQL yet. heres what access spat out when i set up the update query

```
UPDATE (tblCustomers
        INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblCustomers.\[CustNum\] = tblOrders.\[CustNum\])
       INNER JOIN tblOrdProdNum ON tblOrders.\[OrderNum\] = tblOrdProdNum.\[OrderNum\]
SET tblOrdProdNum.AmountPaid = \[tblLoyaltyLevel\].\[SumOfAmountPaid\],
    tblCustomers.CustNum = \[tblLoyaltyLevel\].\[CustNum\];
```